# Numpy Memmap Ctypes Access

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes, numpy-memmap

I'm trying to use a very large numpy array using numpy memmap, accessing each element as a ctypes Structure.

```
class My_Structure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('field1', c_uint32, 3),
                ('field2', c_uint32, 2),
                ('field3', c_uint32, 2),
                ('field4', c_uint32, 9),
                ('field5', c_uint32, 12),
                ('field6', c_uint32, 2),
                ('field7', c_uint32, 2)]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'MyStruct -- f1{self.field1} f2{self.field2} f3{self.field3} f3{self.field4} f5{self.field5} f6{self.field6} f7{self.field7}'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for field in self._fields_:
            if getattr(self, field[0]) != getattr(other, field[0]):
                return False
            return True

_big_array = np.memmap(filename = 'big_file.data',
                                   dtype = 'uint32',
                                   mode = 'w+',
                                   shape = 1000000
                                   )

big_array = _big_array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(My_Structure))

big_array[0].field1 = 5
...
```

And it seems to work correctly, but I'm getting an fault on a 64bit Windows machine where python.exe simply stops.  In Event Viewer, I see that the faulting module name is `_ctypes.pyd` and the exception code is 0xc0000005 which I believe is an access exception.

I don't seem to be getting the same error on Linux, though my testing has not been thorough.

My questions are:

1. Does my access look correct; ie. am I using `numpy.memmap.ctypes.data_as` correctly?
2. Does the fact that I have functions (`__str__` and `__eq__`) defined on `My_Structure` change its size? ie. can it still be used in the array as a `uint32`?
3. Is there anything that you think might cause this behavior? Particularly considering the differences between Windows and Linux?

EDIT:

2. Using `ctypes.addressof` and `ctypes.sizeof` on big_array elements, it looks like the `__str__` and `__eq__` do not impact the size of `My_Structure`
3. I added some asserts before my access to `big_array` and found that I was attempting to access `big_array[-1]`, which explains the access error and crash.

Which leaves question 1 open: It looks like my code is technically correct, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to access the numpy array than using a ctypes.pointer so that I still get the benefits of using a numpy array (out-of-bound access warning, negative index wrapping, etc.).  Daniel below suggested using a structured numpy array, but is it possible to do bitfield access with this?

Comment: why not use structured numpy-array?

Comment: Hi Daniel, the main reason is that my Structure uses bitfields of various lengths. My understanding is that the smallest dtype in a structured array is a byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to `ctypes` at the last step, not the first step:

```
_big_array[0, ...].ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(My_Structure)).field1 = 5
```

Note that `...` is needed to keep the result as a 0d array, so that the `.ctypes` attribute exists

Now of course, negative indexing will work just fine:

```
_big_array[-1, ...].ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(My_Structure)).field1 = 5
```

---

> Daniel below suggested using a structured numpy array, but is it possible to do bitfield access with this?

No